# How can I extract a react fragment into it's own component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a description list in React like the following below. A requirement I am trying to add is to allow it to be recursive. An example of how you would use it below.

```
<DescriptionList>
    <DescriptionListItem key="1" term="First Name" description="Ryan" />
    <DescriptionListItem key="2" term="Last Name" description="Me" />
    <DescriptionListItem key="3" term="Email" description="emample@mail.com" />
    <DescriptionList>
      <DescriptionListItem key="1" term="term1" description="value 1" />
      <DescriptionListItem key="2" term="term2" description="value 2" />
      <DescriptionListItem key="3" term="term3" description="value 3" />
    </DescriptionList>
</DescriptionList>
```

I wanted to use something like the html [definition list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp)

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import createFragment from 'react-addons-create-fragment';

class DescriptionList extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.children);
    return (
      <dl className="row">
        {this.props.children.map(child => createDescriptionListItemFragment(child))}
      </dl>
    );
  }
}

function createDescriptionListItemFragment({props}) {
  let fragment = {};
  fragment.term = <dt>{props.term}</dt>;
  fragment.description = <dd>{props.description}</dd>;
  fragment = createFragment(fragment);
  return fragment;
}

DescriptionList.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default DescriptionList;
```

Above is a first round implementation of it. I was hoping to extract the `DescriptionListItem` into it's own component and handle the `DescriptionListItem` logic there. I only managed to get everything working in a single component since `createFragment` returns an array of ReactElements. It seems you can't return a fragment as a react component. I can't wrap the fragment in a `div` since it needs to sit inside the `dl`.

Any ideas how I can extract the logic into it's own component?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how I can extract the logic into it's own component?

Not in versions of the React library **< 16.2.0**. 
In 16.2.0, support for fragments was added.

However, logic for `DescriptionListItem` currently in `createDescriptionListItemFragment` can refactored as in the following way.

```
const DescriptionListItem = ({props}, index) => {
  const {term, description} = props;
  return [ 
     <dt key={`${term}-${index}`}>{term}</dt>,
     <dd key={`${description}-${index}`}>{description}</dd>
  ];
}
```

`DescriptionListItem` is a function that returns a fragment and as such can be passed as the mapper.

```
class DescriptionList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <dl className="row">
        {this.props.children.map(DescriptionListItem)}
      </dl>
    );
  }
}
```